# Phone and computer clock out of sync

Tags: wireless-networking, ntp

My girlfriend experiences a behavior I cannot explain.

She has a phone (Google Pixel 5) and a laptop (Apple MacBook Pro M1) which both get their system clock out-of-sync by anywhere from 5 minutes up to 30 minutes whenever she goes to work, even though each device is configured to sync their clock using network time servers. If that's relevant to the question, it happens inside a hospital.

She tells me multiple people working there are experiencing the same issue on their phone, even those who have never connected to the hospital Wi-Fi.

The devices can clearly communicate with the network as can be seen in this google search for the current time showing a 24 minutes drift:

[image: as can be seen in this google search for the current time showing a 24 minutes drift]

Diagnostics related to dead CMOS batteries are very unlikely given that the laptop is brand new.

What could be causing this issue ?

Comment: Sounds like the times on the hospital network are wrong. She should speak to the hospitals IT department.

Comment: I used to use sntp on one of our servers, so all connected devices such as ip phones and computer sync time locally. probably they have such service on their server or a router which have wrong time settings.

Comment: Any MRI machines nearby?

Comment: @DavidPostill how would the time of the hospital network infrastructure influence the time retrieved from external time servers used to sync system clocks ?

Comment: @user1686 there are indeed 3 MRI scanners nearby, the Mac device have been ~10 meters from them at the closest. Don't know if there are any IT rooms near them though, I would hope not.

Comment: I mean it reminds me strongly of the "helium leak causing problems for iPhones" story from 2018

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Android, but try setting the Mac to a specific set of fallback servers, e.g

`pool.ntp.org., time.apple.com., time.windows.com., time.cloudflare.com.`

You can do this in the Date & Time system pref. This is Mojave, it's probably changed visually on newer OSes, but is functionally the same.

[image]

Try copy/pasting the line from above into where the picture says `Apple Europe (time.euro.apple.com.`) [the trailing`.` may look odd, but it's an Apple convention.]
*From comments, this isn't an Apple convention it's a DNS syntax convention.*

At a guess, something on the local network is mis-configured, as this is affecting many people on many devices. That should bypass any local NTP server which may be interfering & test those specific four.
Somebody needs to tell IT.

Comment: FYI, the final dot is not an Apple convention. It's a longstanding DNS syntax convention that many have forgotten, but some at Apple have not. It specifies that it's a complete FQDN, and that the DNS search domain (if one has been configured) should not be appended to the end of the provided hostname string.